# Distinguish function from extension

Tags: kotlin

I tried to write a funtion, which can be inserted in any expresion, in order to log the value:

```kotlin
val x = (2.debug() + 3.debug()).debug("2+3")
```

But instead I wrote the following endless loop:

```kotlin
fun debug (message: String) {
    Log.d (R.string.app_name.toString(), message) }

fun <T> T.debug (tag: String = "value"): T {
    debug ("$tag: $this")
    return this 
}
```

My aim was to write a "normal" function (1st) and an extension function (2nd) and the extension function should call the normal function.

The problem in my code is: the extension function calls itself instead of the normal function. I do not understand this, because I did not specify an instance receiver in the extension function.

How to fix this?

Comment: `this` is implicit instance receiver in a member or extension method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given you have different param names in each function, you could change the second function to call the first one with named arguments:

```kotlin
fun <T> T.debug (tag: String = "value"): T {
    debug (message = "$tag: $this")
    return this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to strip `this` out of extension method, so the best way out would be to create differently named wrapper:

```
fun <T> T.debug (tag: String = "value"): T {
    debugWrapper( "$tag: $this")
    return this
}

fun debug (message: String) {
    Log.d ("tag", message)
}

private fun debugWrapper (message: String) {
    debug(message)
}
```

I think you were looking to keep existing calls to `debug` and this delivers.

I've tried to look into decompiled code (minus the default parameter, for clarity) in hope to differentiate them by namespace:

```
public final class TestclassKt {
    public static final Object debug(Object $this$debug, @NotNull String tag) {
        Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(tag, "tag");
        debug($this$debug, tag + ": " + $this$debug);
        return $this$debug;
    }

    public static final void debug(@NotNull String message) {
        Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(message, "message");
        Log.d("tag", message);
    }
}
```

But the 2 methods are in same namespace and the only way to differentiate them is by arguments.

I think you've broken Kotlin.